# Using PDO with php

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to use PDO for the first time, I have researched for a couple days trying to get a couple things setup with it. I'm not getting any errors, but when using test messages, I do not receive the Test1 message.

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
            if(isset($_POST["firstname"]) && isset($_POST["lastname"]) && isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["email"])
                    && isset($_POST["password"]) && isset($_POST["confirm"])){
                $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
                $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
                $username = $_POST["username"];
                $email = $_POST["email"];
                $password = $_POST["password"];
                $confirm = $_POST["confirm"];
                $hash = md5(rand(0,1000));

                $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username');
                $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
                $stmt->execute();
                if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                    $error_msg = "Username is taken!";
                }else{
                    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :email');
                    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                        $error_msg = "Email is taken!";
                    }else{
                        if($password==$confirm){
                            echo "Test";
                            $encryptpass = md5($password);
                            //insert user data into database
                            echo "Test3";
                            $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname, username, email, password, hash) 
                                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
                            $stmt->bindParam("ssssss", $firstname, $lastname, $username, $email, $password, $hash);
                            $stmt->execute();
                            echo "Test1";
                            $success_msg = "Thank you for registering with CrystalDev! \nPlease activate your account by
                                            clicking the link in your email!";

                            $to = $email;
                            $subject = 'Signup | Verification';
                            $message = 'Thanks for signing up!
                                            Your account has been created!
                                            Please click this link to activate your account:
                                            http://www.crystaldev.net/verify.php?email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash.'
                                                    ';
                            $headers = 'From:noreply@crystaldev.net' . "\r\n"; // Set from headers
                            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // Send our email
                        }else{
                            $error_msg = "Passwords do not match!";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

SOLUTION (EDITED):
I found my problem.. I was using a column name that didn't exist in the database I was using.

Comment: check if the first `execute()` worked.

Comment: 1. Turn up error_reporting so you can actually see the errors. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php 2. Don't mix up mysqli and PDO. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php 3. Don't use MD5 for passwords, this is not 1996. http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: You are mixing `mysqli` syntax with `PDO`. These are different drivers and don't work together. Specifically here, `bindParam("ssssss"` get rid of the `s`s. I also would send the userID in the email rather than the actual email address, if using the email address though URL encode it.